# curl_exec($ch) not executing on external domains anymore, why?

Tags: php, curl

I was using cURL to scrape content from a site and just recently my page stated hanging when it reached `curl_exec($ch)`. After some tests I noticed that it could load any other page from my own domain but when attempting to load from anything external I'll get a `connect() timeout!` error.

Here's a simplified version of what I was using:

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://www.google.com');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);

$contents = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

echo $contents;
?>
```

Here's some info I have about my host from my `phpinfo()`:

```
PHP Version 5.3.1
cURL support       enabled
cURL Information    7.19.7
Host    i686-pc-linux-gnu
```

I don't have access to SSH or modifying the php.ini file (however I can read it). But is there a way to tell if something was recently set to block cURL access to external domains? Or is there something else I might have missed?

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: Probably a firewall. Is this your own personal machine? Or a hosted one somewhere? The code looks fine, so most likely something external to your box.

Comment: It's hosted somewhere. I guess it must have been firewalled recently. Is there a way to test if it's indeed being blocked by a firewall?

Comment: Could try some barebones fsockopen() using port 80 and google's ip. if that fails as well, then it's not just curl affected.

Comment: Thanks. I tried connecting to cnn.com with the example script on php.net and received this error: `Warning: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to www.cnn.com:80 (Connection timed out) in ***/test2.php on line 2` so that means that all connections to port 80 have been blocked?
Connection timed out (110)

Comment: Most likely, yes. You'll have to check with your provider to figure out what's blocking things. could be a firewall on your box, or something farther upstream.

Comment: Thanks for you input. I'll research this more.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware about any setting like that, it would not make much sense.
As you said you are on a remote webserver without console access I guess that your activity has been detected by the host or  more likely it caused issues and so they firewalled you.
A silent iptables DROP would cause this.

When scraping google you need to use proxies for more than a few hand full of requests and you should never abuse your webservers primary IP if it's not your own. That's likely a breach of their TOS and could even result in legal action if they get banned from Google (which can happen).

Take a look at [Google rank checker](http://google-rank-checker.squabbel.com) that's a PHP script that does exactly what you want using CURL and proper IP management.

I can't think of anything that's causing a timeout than a firewall on your side.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I was using google.com in my sample code as an example, but I guess I should be careful. It seems then that it must be a firewall issue.

Comment: Some hosting providers like hostgator or godaddy do have a firewall in place by default.
Maybe just contact your hosting provider live support (that's often available) and ask them if there is any sort of firewall restricting outgoing TCP connections to port 80. (that's for normal HTTP requests)  
From my experience it was never an issue to open such a firewall.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the info. I guess I can try contacting the admin.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're getting a `connect() timeout!` error, but the following line:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
```

If it's not set to 1, it will not return any of the page's content back into your `$contents`.

Comment: You're right, I had it at 1 and changed to 0 to test it. But interestingly it worked on a friends server whether I had it at 1 or 0.